# FaultedException: formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize

Tags: wcf, collections, deserialization, readonly, formatter

App fails with exception when it calls method *Save(A a);*

{"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error deserializing parameter http://tempuri.org/:infs. InnerException message was \" type Collection Api.BrainDictionary.Editor.DataTrasferObjects, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null]] \ ", intended only for the return, would return null. Input stream includes elements of the collection that can not be added if the value of the instance is null . Try to initialize a collection in a method getter. \ ". For details, see InnerException. "}

but **my collection "IFNLs" is not readonly**

```
   [DataContract]
    public class A
    {

            [DataMember]
            public List<B> GVs{get; set ;}

            [DataMember]
            public List<C> SREs{get;set;}

            [DataMember]
            public List<D> TEs{get;set;}

            [DataMember]
            public List<E> INFLs{get;set;}
    }
```

---

```
[DataContract]
public class E
{
       [DataMember]
       public long Id {get;set;}

       [DataMember]
       public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

This bug does not appear if
 1. Property "Infls" is empty, but not null; Other Properties are not empty.
 2. Property "Infls" is not empty. Other Properties are empty.

Classes B,C,D,E **do not** refer to each other.
I think, may be, binding quotes are limited. But increasing binding quotes does not help me. I add to DataContractSerializerOperationBehaviour, and set maxItemsInObjectGraph, this solution does not help me too....